# Specify the colors used when applying to backgrounds and fonts SharePoint online Modern

Tags: sharepoint-online, branding, modern-experience

I have already deployed a theme to my Modern sharepoint site, but I have an ask from the stakeholders to remove the ootb colors that are used for enhanced rich text and replace with company branded colors.

Is this even possible?

Thank you in advance.

Dorinda

Comment: Where all you wanted to change the color?? It’s possible by modifying the master page

Comment: So what I am trying to figure out is how, i just want to remove the default standard colors that are available in a content editor webpart or anywhere rich text is used.  the standard colors dont match...that is what I am trying to find out.